# How to share a video to facebook page from android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I am developing android app in which user can play videos, I want to provide a feature so that users can share these videos to specific facebook page (not their own timeline), I have searched in facebook sdk documentation and I found [Sharing on Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) but it enable user to share videos to their own timeline

does anybody knows how to enable users to share videos to specific facebook page ??

Comment: specific facebook page means login user's page or particular page in facebook...?

Comment: its facebook fan page

Comment: A page that they own or other peoples pages?

Comment: a fan page that user liked it